# Clopen and open sets have the same measure

Tags: measure-theory

I was positive I had already asked this one but apparently not. It is simply this:

> Show that the Lebesgue outer measure of $[a,b)$ is $b-a$.

Let $\mathscr{K}$ be the collection of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ a nonnegative setfunction defined on $\mathscr{K}$ by $\lambda(\emptyset)=0$ and $\lambda\{(a,b)\}=b-a$ for $(a,b) \in \mathscr{K}$. Then the Lebesgue outer measure is defined as $\mu^*(A)=\mathrm{inf} \{ \sum \lambda(E_n) \mid E_n \in \mathscr{K},\mathrm{ } \cup E_n \supset A \}$. So, how does one go about answering the question when the outer measure is defined on open subsets?

I figure one should work with limits in some way. Perhaps $[a,b)$ can be considered as the union of $(a,b)$ with $\cup (a-\varepsilon_n,a+\varepsilon_n)$ "where $\varepsilon_n$ goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity", whatever that would mean in terms of the latter open sets. If we let the $E_n$ be $(a,b)$ and the $(a-\varepsilon_n,a+\varepsilon_n)$ then we have $\sum \lambda(E_n) = b-a+2 \sum \varepsilon_n$. For the moment ignoring that this is totally not rigorous and possibly nonsensical, the desired result follows if we can define $\varepsilon_n$ properly. Or maybe not...

Anyway those are my thoughts. Can you give me some hints on how to really do this? :P Thanks.

Comment: Note that "clopen" usually means a set that is _both_ open and closed, whereas you seem to be speaking of a half-open interval which is _neither_ open nor closed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oops sorry about that. Hopefully it's obvious that the title can be disregarded in light of the actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sets $(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$.

We then have that $\mu^*([a,b)) \leq b - a +\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$ since $[a,b) \subseteq (a- \frac{1}{n},b)$, for all $n$.

Now we also have that $(a,b) \subset [a,b)$ so it must be that $b-a = \mu^*((a,b)) \leq \mu^*([a,b))$.

So we have that $\mu^*([a,b)) = b-a$.

Comment: Oh, it follows from the monotonicity of $\mu^*$. Thanks!